# merging short text fragment on long sentence

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I would like to place the small text fragments on the long sentence such as following

Input_full sentence

```
TRSTUVWSRTPSAREWSTRESW
```

list of short fragments

```
TRST 
RESW
```

Output

I want the output such that wherever the short fragments match, it can be visible and placed exactly below the long sentence

```
TRSTUVWSRTPSAREWSTRESW 
||||              |||| 
TRST              RESW
```

Comment: This sounds very much like a homework assignment.

Comment: I am not programmer, but in order to analyse my proteomics mass spectrometry data I needed such text processing

Answer (score 1):

With some python:

```py
#! /usr/bin/python3

import sys

textfile = 'input.txt'
patfile = 'patterns.txt'

with open(textfile) as text:
    with open(patfile) as pat:
        patterns = [line.strip() for line in pat]

        for line in text:
            line = line.strip()
            print(line)
            out = line[:]
            for p in patterns:
                out = out.replace(p, '|'*len(p))
            print(''.join(v if v == '|' else ' ' for v in out))
            print(''.join(line[k] if v == '|' else ' ' for k, v in enumerate(out)))
```

Essentially, this does, for each line in the input file:

1. Prints the line, and takes a copy.
2. For every pattern, replace the occurrences of the pattern in the line with `|` in the copy.
3. Then it prints the copy with everything except `|` replaced with spaces.
4. Then it prints the original line's character wherever `|` occurs in the copy, or spaces otherwise.

I assume that the patterns are fixed string which don't contain `|`.

Comment: This works fine, but whenever I have longer sentence it does not align completely (only half of its correctly aligned). Also I should have mentioned that my sentence does not contain any space.

Comment: @Trupti :shrug: unless you give a proper example, there's nothing I can do